# How to change IIS application pool from x64 to x86

Tags: asp.net, application-pool

I am afraid to see the error `Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.hMailServer' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.` while running a web application. The problem is I am running 32 bit web application in 64bit. Well, Visual Studio allows to change the built option to 32/64 but I just have web project with the source files to recompile by Google hours together I found this http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/07/03/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-presentationcore-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-a-solution/ hope it helps me. But I am working on windows 2003 server. Can anybody please tell me how to convert the application to run in 64 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have had to run this on numerous x64 '03 machines to support older components.

[Run x86 bit applications on x64 - Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/405f5bb5-87a3-43d2-8138-54b75db73aa1.mspx?mfr=true)

Start - Run - Navigate to :

`%systemdrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts`

Run this statement:

`cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 1`

**EDIT 2** I hope this helps.

I went through some of my old documents and found this syntax I used succesfully before:

`cscript %SYSTEMDRIVE%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1`

Also, remember to register IIS when it completes (in your .NET folder run)

**EDIT 3**

Start - Run - Enter the following:

`%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

Without harping on - allow the .aspx extension in IIS afterwards as well.

Comment: While running the above code I am getting error `Expected end of statement` with error code `800A0401`

Comment: Nope error is at Char 25.. please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443775/error-code-800a0401-while-running-vb-script

Comment: But the error says at char 25 i.e. at the end of code `adsutil.vbs` and the error is `Expected end of statement`.

Comment: sorry i cant be of more assistance but see my edit 2: it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: How to register IIS. How to perform the task `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3527/discussion-between-kars-and-f0x)