# Error code 800A0401 while running VB script

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to run X86 application in x64. For that Microsoft provided with the below code at http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/405f5bb5-87a3-43d2-8138-54b75db73aa1.mspx?mfr=true

```
cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 “true”
```

While running this script I am getting error

at char 25
Description: Expected end statement
Code: 800A0401

I don't know VBscript syntax to check. Please help me.

Comment: Does the error message include the line number on which the error occurs?

Comment: Yeah! but its a one line code. And the error is at char 25 (i.e. at the end of `cscript.exe adsutil.vbs`)

Comment: If it's a VBScript syntax error, it's somewhere in the adsutil.vbs script itself, not in the command line. That's why I'm asking for the line #. Btw, what versions of Windows and IIS are you using?

Comment: I am using server 2003. I am very sure that adsutil.vbs file works fine as I made fresh OS installation also I didn't disturb that file.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is fancy quotes in `“true”`. Try using `"true"` or `true` instead.

Comment: +1 I was going to say the same thing. Someone should tell Microsoft to remove those "smart" quotes from the command on its website...

Comment: The question is very clear that error lies at Char 25 not at the end. However I tried your answer but still the same. Says error at Char 25

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the

```
set
```

in the code. I suggest having it like this:

```
cscript.exe adsutil.vbs
set W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 “true”
```